# how to open many files simultaneously for reading in c

Tags: c++, c, object, filereader

I'm trying to port some of my c++ code into c. I have the following construct

```
class reader{
private:
FILE *fp;
alot_of_data data;//updated by read_until() method
public:
  reader(const char*filename)
  read_until(some conditional dependent on the contents of the file, and the arg supplied)
}
```

Im then instantiating hundreds of these object and iterate over them using several 'read_until()' for each file until allfiles is at eof.

I'm failing to see any clever way to do this in c, the only solution I can come up with is making an array of FILE pointers, and do the same with all the private member data from my class.

But this seems very messy, can I implement the functionality of my class as a function pointer, or anything better, I think I'm missing a fundamental design pattern?

The files are way to big to have all in memory, so reading everything from every file is not feasible
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an abstract data type:

```
typedef struct {
  FILE *fp;
  alot_of_data data;//updated by read_until() method
} reader;

void init_reader(reader* that, const char* filename);
void read_until(reader* that, some conditional dependent on the contents of the file, and the arg supplied)
```

Then you can create and use objects of this type just as with objects of the class, except that, instead of `obj.func()`, you write `func(&obj)`:

```
reader r;
init_reader(&r, "blah.txt");
read_until(&r, /* ... */);
```

Answer (score 1):

The principle of information hiding is the same, regardless of the language you use. Just move the stuff you want to hide into the source file:

```
// reader.h
typedef struct reader reader;

reader* new_reader(const char*filename);
void read_until(reader*, ...);

// reader.c

struct reader {
    FILE *fp;
    alot_of_data data;//updated by read_until() method
};

reader *new_reader(const char*filename) { ... }
void read_until(reader*, ...) { ... }
```

Comment: I had the impression `read_until` was supposed to work on a bunch of files, but on re-reading that looks wrong. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just convert the data into a struct:

```
struct reader
{
  FILE *file;
  alot_of_data data;
};
```

Then define ordinary functions, that take a `struct reader` as their first argument:

```
int reader_construct(struct reader *r, const char *filename)
{
  if((r->file = fopen(filename, "rt")) == NULL)
    return 0;
  /* do other inits */
  return 1;
}
```

and the reader function becomes:

```
int read_until(struct reader *r, arguments)
{
  /* lots of interesting code */
}
```

Then just have an array of structures, call `reader_construct()` on them and then do the `read_until()` calls as required.

You could of course opt for a more dynamic constructor, that returns the "object":

```
struct reader * reader_new(const char *filename)
{
  struct reader *r = malloc(sizeof *r);
  if(r == NULL)
    return NULL;
  if(reader_construct(r, filename))
    return r;
  return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a structure to hold all the related information, and then loop over that... Just an idea... (I think C supports structures - it's been a while...)